# EF 5 Add-Migration create a foreign key for GET only property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

Here is my code

The Gallery class

```
public class Gallery
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PhotoGallery> Photos { get; set; }
   public List<PhotoGallery> ActivePhotos 
   { 
      get { return this.Photos.Where(/*condition*/); 
   }
}
```

The Photo class

```
public class Photo
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}
```

The PhotoGallery class

```
public class PhotoGallery
{
   public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
   public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
   public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

If I run Add-Migration command, it will generate a relation for Gallery.ActivePhotos which I don't want. My question is, is that the default behavior of EF5? Before this, I remember that the GET only property like this will never be mapped at all. Or am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  annotation to your property like so:

```
public class Gallery
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PhotoGallery> Photos { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public List<PhotoGallery> ActivePhotos 
   { 
      get { return this.Photos.Where(/*condition*/); 
   }
}
```

I haven't found anything that says this is new to EF5, but I am using EF 4.3.1 and have read only properties like in your question that don't map.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ben-tidman but that's what I'm doing. Just curious about the behavior.